# Paul Butler diff algorithm fatal error and results not showing up

Tags: php, diff

Wow I've got a lot of questions today...
So I managed to fix the code I used for Paul Butler's diff algorithm a bit. However, while there doesn't seem to be a problem with the code itself, it's not comparing the two text values I want it to compare from the database. I was wondering if there was a specific reason for that? Or maybe it has to do with the fact that it's all in a table? Not sure, but either way, there's just a blank space there...
Also, when putting the code with different values for $old and $new, it now says:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare diff() (previously declared in /home/equinox/public_html/admins/profile-tool_elizabeth.php:125) in /home/equinox/public_html/admins/profile-tool_elizabeth.php on line 169

I don't know why that is... line 125 is the first "function diff" and 169 is "function diff" for the next two values I want to compare. Not sure what's happening there...

here's basically the whole code:

```
<?php

  session_start();

   while ($nSELECT = mysql_fetch_object($SELECT)) {

        echo "

          <tr bgcolor=\"#000000\">

           <td><a href=\"$PHP_SELF?id=" . $nSELECT->userid . "\">" . getName($nSELECT->userid) . "</a></td>


          </tr>

        ";

      }

    }

    echo "</table><p>";

  } elseif (empty($_GET['s']) && !empty($_GET['id'])) {

    $SELECT = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM profile_edit WHERE userid = '$id'") or die(mysql_error()); 
    $SELECT = mysql_fetch_object($SELECT);

    $USERINFO = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE id = '$id'") or die(mysql_error());
    $USERINFO = mysql_fetch_object($USERINFO);

    $oldhistory = mysql_query("SELECT history FROM members WHERE id = '$id'") or die(mysql_error());
    $oldhistory = mysql_fetch_object($oldhistory);

    $newhistory = mysql_query("SELECT history FROM profile_edit WHERE userid = '$id'") or die(mysql_error());   
    $newhistory = mysql_fetch_object($newhistory);

    $OLDPERSONALITY = mysql_query("SELECT personality FROM members WHERE id = '$id'") or die(mysql_error());
    $OLDPERSONALITY = mysql_fetch_object($OLDPERSONALITY);

    $NEWPERSONALITY = mysql_query("SELECT personality FROM profile_edit WHERE userid = '$id'") or die(mysql_error());   
    $NEWPERSONALITY = mysql_fetch_object($NEWPERSONALITY);

    $OLDAPPEARANCE = mysql_query("SELECT description FROM members WHERE id = '$id'") or die(mysql_error());
    $OLDAPPEARANCE = mysql_fetch_object($OLDAPPEARANCE);

    $NEWAPPEARANCE = mysql_query("SELECT personality FROM profile_edit WHERE userid = '$id'") or die(mysql_error());    
    $NEWAPPEARANCE = mysql_fetch_object($NEWAPPEARANCE);




    echo "

      <form action=\"$PHP_SELF?id=$id&s=a\" method=\"post\">

      <table cellpadding=\"5\" cellspacing=\"1\" border=\"0\" align=\"center\" bgcolor=\"#234904\">

        <tr bgcolor=\"#000000\">

         <td>Username :: </td>

         <td><a href=\"/profile.php?id=".$SELECT->userid."\" target=\"_blank\">" . getName($SELECT->userid) ."</a> (Click to see current profile in new window)</td>

        <tr bgcolor=\"#000000\">

         <td>Species :: </td>

         <td>" . $USERINFO->species2 ." -> ". $USERINFO->subspecies ." (". $USERINFO->clan .")</td>

        <tr bgcolor=\"#000000\">

         <td>History :: </td>
         <td> 
";

function diff($oldhistory, $newhistory){
    foreach($oldhistory as $oindex => $ovalue){
        $nkeys = array_keys($newhistory, $ovalue);
        foreach($nkeys as $nindex){
            $matrix[$oindex][$nindex] = isset($matrix[$oindex - 1][$nindex - 1]) ?
                $matrix[$oindex - 1][$nindex - 1] + 1 : 1;
            if($matrix[$oindex][$nindex] > $maxlen){
                $maxlen = $matrix[$oindex][$nindex];
                $omax = $oindex + 1 - $maxlen;
                $nmax = $nindex + 1 - $maxlen;
            }
        }   
    }
    if($maxlen == 0) return array(array('d'=>$oldhistory, 'i'=>$newhistory));
    return array_merge(
        diff(array_slice($oldhistory, 0, $omax), array_slice($newhistory, 0, $nmax)),
        array_slice($newhistory, $nmax, $maxlen),
        diff(array_slice($oldhistory, $omax + $maxlen), array_slice($newhistory, $nmax + $maxlen)));
}

function htmlDiff($oldhistory, $newhistory){
    $diff = diff(explode(' ', $oldhistory), explode(' ', $newhistory));
    foreach($diff as $k){
        if(is_array($k))
            $ret .= (!empty($k['d'])?"<del>".implode(' ',$k['d'])."</del> ":'').
                (!empty($k['i'])?"<ins>".implode(' ',$k['i'])."</ins> ":'');
        else $ret .= $k . ' ';
    }
    return $ret;
}



echo "</td>

        </tr>


        <tr bgcolor=\"#000000\">

         <td>Description :: </td>

         <td>";

function diff($oldappearance, $newappearance){
    foreach($oldappearance as $oindex => $ovalue){
        $nkeys = array_keys($newappearance, $ovalue);
        foreach($nkeys as $nindex){
            $matrix[$oindex][$nindex] = isset($matrix[$oindex - 1][$nindex - 1]) ?
                $matrix[$oindex - 1][$nindex - 1] + 1 : 1;
            if($matrix[$oindex][$nindex] > $maxlen){
                $maxlen = $matrix[$oindex][$nindex];
                $omax = $oindex + 1 - $maxlen;
                $nmax = $nindex + 1 - $maxlen;
            }
        }   
    }
    if($maxlen == 0) return array(array('d'=>$oldappearance, 'i'=>$newappearance));
    return array_merge(
        diff(array_slice($oldappearance, 0, $omax), array_slice($newappearance, 0, $nmax)),
        array_slice($newappearance, $nmax, $maxlen),
        diff(array_slice($oldappearance, $omax + $maxlen), array_slice($newappearance, $nmax + $maxlen)));
}

function htmlDiff($oldappearance, $newappearance){
    $diff = diff(explode(' ', $oldappearance), explode(' ', $newappearance));
    foreach($diff as $k){
        if(is_array($k))
            $ret .= (!empty($k['d'])?"<del>".implode(' ',$k['d'])."</del> ":'').
                (!empty($k['i'])?"<ins>".implode(' ',$k['i'])."</ins> ":'');
        else $ret .= $k . ' ';
    }
    return $ret;
}


echo "</td>


        </tr>


        <tr bgcolor=\"#000000\">

         <td>Description :: </td>

         <td>";

function diff($oldappearance, $newappearance){
    foreach($oldappearance as $oindex => $ovalue){
        $nkeys = array_keys($newappearance, $ovalue);
        foreach($nkeys as $nindex){
            $matrix[$oindex][$nindex] = isset($matrix[$oindex - 1][$nindex - 1]) ?
                $matrix[$oindex - 1][$nindex - 1] + 1 : 1;
            if($matrix[$oindex][$nindex] > $maxlen){
                $maxlen = $matrix[$oindex][$nindex];
                $omax = $oindex + 1 - $maxlen;
                $nmax = $nindex + 1 - $maxlen;
            }
        }   
    }
    if($maxlen == 0) return array(array('d'=>$oldappearance, 'i'=>$newappearance));
    return array_merge(
        diff(array_slice($oldappearance, 0, $omax), array_slice($newappearance, 0, $nmax)),
        array_slice($newappearance, $nmax, $maxlen),
        diff(array_slice($oldappearance, $omax + $maxlen), array_slice($newappearance, $nmax + $maxlen)));
}

function htmlDiff($oldappearance, $newappearance){
    $diff = diff(explode(' ', $oldappearance), explode(' ', $newappearance));
    foreach($diff as $k){
        if(is_array($k))
            $ret .= (!empty($k['d'])?"<del>".implode(' ',$k['d'])."</del> ":'').
                (!empty($k['i'])?"<ins>".implode(' ',$k['i'])."</ins> ":'');
        else $ret .= $k . ' ';
    }
    return $ret;
}


echo "</td>

        </tr>

        <tr bgcolor=\"#000000\">

         <td colspan=\"2\" style=\"text-align: center\"><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Accept\"></td>

        </tr>

      </table>

      </form>

      <p><br>

      <form action=\"$PHP_SELF?id=$id&s=d\" method=\"post\">

    <table cellpadding=\"5\" cellspacing=\"1\" border=\"0\" align=\"center\" bgcolor=\"#234904\">

      <tr bgcolor=\"#000000\">

         <td>Reason :: </td>

         <td><textarea name=\"reason\" rows=\"6\" cols=\"30\"></textarea></td>

        </tr>

        <tr bgcolor=\"#000000\">

         <td colspan=\"2\" style=\"text-align: center\"><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Deny\"></td>

        </tr>

      </table>

      </form>

    ";

  } 


  incFooter();

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename your function from `diff` to something else.  That error message happens if you attempt to declare the two functions with the same name in the same scope.

Comment: I need both functions to do the diff thing though... would it not matter if I were to rename it?

Comment: Name one of them differently, then call it by it's new name.  If you have two functions that do the same exact thing and have the same exact name, you could always remove one of them.

Comment: they're all comparing texts, but different ones in each function... do you mean as in merge the three diff functions into the same part? I'll try renaming

Comment: Might want to read up on how functions work.  Aside from having different names for the parameters, the functions do the same exact thing.  The variable names in the function definition are what the function calls them *internally*, it's not the name of the variables *externally*.

Comment: Will definitely do that... -.- thanks so much for the help! it got rid of the error, I renamed all "diff" parts to "diff..." with relevance to the function... however the fields are still empty... any idea why that might be?